# Unicode Char in Java

Tags: java, unicode

In the Arabic Language, characters have different representation based on whether in the beginning, middle or the end of a word:

```
خ‎    062E
ﺥ‎    FEA5
ـخ‎   FEA6
ـخـ‎  FEA8
خـ‎   FEA7
```

These are the same letter but in different positions.

When I use the normal `(int) B.charAt(x)` I get the Unicode value of the character (062E).

Is there a method to get the value based on the position?

Comment: If you are using the right character at the right position, you won't need a method like that (which also doesn't exist).

Answer (score 3):

Arabic text is typically not stored in its representation, but only in its abstract form (such as U+062E). It is up to the *renderer* to apply the Unicode Algorithm and transform the input range into an output range consisting of presentational characters, order them correctly and then render them with the appropriate glyphs from the chosen font.

Comment: U+062E isn’t really an isolated-form character but a generic character, with its position abstracted away. Its glyph typically reflects isolated position, since the glyph is normally not used when the character is rendered in normal text context.